# How to get user's time zone in Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently, need to get a user's office location and then convert that into a time zone, or is there a way to obtain the user's time zone Graph?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve this question.  Great questions tend to get quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 5):

[Mailbox settings](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/mailboxsettings) has a timezone property.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailboxsettings
```

Comment: Link to additional documentation page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/user-get-mailboxsettings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http&WT.mc_id=docs-stackoverflow-scottca#http-request

Answer (score 1):

According to your descriptions, I assume you want to get the user's time zone by Graph.

In [this document](http://%20https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get_mailboxsettings#http-request), we can get the user's mailbox Settings. We can use the API like this:

`GET /me/mailboxSettings/timeZone`

or

`GET /users/{id|userPrincipalName}/mailboxSettings/timeZone`

It will return the user's mailbox time zone settings. The response like this:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/XXX/mailboxSettings/timeZone",
"value": "China Standard Time"
}
```